# Why won't Skype install?

Tags: 12.10, skype

I have 64-bit 12.10 Ubuntu. I can't get Skype to install from the software center because it can't find the repositories. I can't install it from the website either. I tried checking the 64-bit Debian package in case it would work and it installed but it won't open. What should I do?

Comment: if you already installed your skype from deb file, run this command so that it will install dependecies `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 2):

I've had some problems with the Software Center as well.

Try to install [lib32stdc++6 [image: Install lib32stdc++6]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lib32stdc++6):

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Then `cd` to the directory where you downloaded the Skype.deb file. If you downloaded it to your Downloads folder, you would type:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Then install the .deb package.

```
sudo dpkg -i skype*.deb
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I installed the wrong Skype package because it still isn't working. Where did you get yours?

Comment: I downloaded the 64 bit .deb file from skype.com. What error are you getting? After you install it with dpkg -i, try doing "sudo apt-get install f"