# Why Skype and fogger are not available in 12.10 software center?

Tags: 12.10, software-center, skype

Why neither Skype nor Fogger are available in 12.10 software center? Even after I enabled Canonical partners' sources in Software Sources.

Edit:
The Fogger is still not available via SC even though it's available via web version of SC [Fogger for ubuntu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fogger/) I perfer not to use Terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/211868/why-wont-skype-install

Comment: @Hckr It isn't a duplicate: the author of the other question had the Skype package and didn't specify where he found it. This question asks where the Skype package can be found and why it isn't in the software center

Comment: "Even after I enabled Canonical partners' sources in Software Sources." And you also updated the sources after enabling it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I re-started SC - this one I'm sure of. So Skype will not be listed on a fresh 12.10 install unless you enable the 'partners' in Software sources? / Q2: Why Fogger isn't available while it's available in the online Software Center?

Comment: I think I didn't update sources but also I doubt I supposed to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/841456

Comment: Please explain the Fogger case so I can accept an answear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is enable "Canonical Partners" software.

Just open "Software Sources" from Unity menu, then "Other Software" tab and check the "Canonical Partners" checkbox. After authorising this change with your password I did update of my repos in console:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After all you will find Skype even as software suggestion in Unity menu.

Comment: This does not answer the part of the question about Fogger though...

Answer (score 2):

It is in the software center. Did you select any filters in the view?

[image]

Comment: None that I know of. I've experienced it on two different machines with practically fresh 12.10 installs - one 32 and one 64-bit. On the 64-bit one (my main system) I pressed the 'All software button' AFTER 'skype' query returned nothing. To no avail. It was yesterday. Today I see Skype listed but only after I enter the full 'skype'. 'skyp' returns nothing. Also 'fogger' still returns nothing while it's shown as available in the online version of the software center.

Answer (score 2):

However, fogger is still not in the Ubuntu Software Center (I've seen a couple posts saying that the developer is moving his residence and some stuff and have it up again in a couple months...)

anyway, I've had success with this:
https://launchpad.net/~loneowais/+archive/fogger/+packages

either one of two ways:
1) add the ppa and install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:loneowais/fogger ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install fogger
```

or 2) download the deb file and install (I prefer GDebi)
https://launchpad.net/~loneowais/+archive/fogger/+files/fogger_0.2.4ppa1-0~236~precise1_all.deb

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of an old question but it should be pointed out that Fogger is basically a dead project.

I was a member of the FogApp Authors Team and I have not had any conversations or email replies from Owais in about 6 months and Fogger has not been updated for about a year now so I am pretty sure that it is safe to say it is a Dead Project.

This is quite unfortunate because the concept of Fogger was AWESOME but sadly it does seem to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

Skype is in the Partner Repository which is why you may not have seen it.  Add the repository and then you will be able to search for it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner
```

Then you should be able to find it in the Ubuntu Software Center

Answer (score 0):

I normally install Skype from it's download page: http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/

Not sure right now, but the version from the repositories were quite old and if you will download a deb package that will install really smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Fogger is dead yet.  Looking at the Launchpad page there have been recent updates.  Bit low on news but still going and I am happier for it :-)

https://launchpad.net/~loneowais/+archive/fogger

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler way....goto

Ubuntu Software Center
Setttings Category
Search "skype"

Im sure you will find it under there rather than searching it from the main page. If you dont find it, go to the status bar (the border at the bottom) of the Ubuntu  Software Center Application, and click on a link that says "SHOW TECHNICAL ITEMS"

Im very sure it will work...